# dojo dataGrid column: how to force an empty column header?

Tags: dojo, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib, dojox.grid.datagrid

Is there any way to force a data grid column's header label to be empty? So far I tried to leave the label property empty, enter a single space, both as fixed text and using ssjs code. But unless I assign some "real" character to the label property the header shows the column's name.

Right now I "resolved" this using css, but since there are only generic style classe for all the column headers I needed to "hack" this using

`.dojoxGridMasterHeader th.dojoxGridCell[idx="0"] div.dojoxGridSortNode{display:none}`...

So I need to address each column by itself just to accomplish the same thing. Not nice.

Anyone having a better idea?
Lothar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-breaking space `'\u00A0'` as data grid column's header label.

```
    <xe:djxDataGridColumn
        id=...
        field=...
        label="#{javascript:'\u00A0'}">
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I had tried to use "&nbsp;" but it wouldn't like that entity...- Thanks, Knut!

Comment: ...btw: you wouldn't know some secret trick how to apply a css class to an individual header element?

Comment: I don't think there is a column's property for styling header or something similar. Your hack on client side would be a starting point to set a style class with CSJS.